# Replace Paragraph Tags from Paragraphs With Only A Single Floated Image with that Image

Tags: jquery, html, css, modx

I am trying to compensate for my WYSIWYG, which surrounds single images with a paragraph tag when not part of a paragraph of other content. This breaks my floats. I would like to remove the paragraph tags containing *only* a *single* image and only if the image has an inline css float attribute in the img tag. I have seen examples, but they do not seem to target that specifically and would break the rest of my content.

I am using Modx, but jQuery would probably be easier (I run v3) than creating a custom output modifier in php.

So:

```
<p><img src="uploads/image.jpg" style="float: right; width: 235px; height: 225px; margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px;" alt="Description" width="235" height="225" class="d-none d-md-block"></p>
```

Becomes:

```
<img src="uploads/image.jpg" style="float: right; width: 235px; height: 225px; margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px;" alt="Description" width="235" height="225" class="d-none d-md-block">
```

Comment: It's easier with Xpath i think. With Jquery We need to loop through paragraphs, and everytime we count images and check for the float. When needed we remove the Parent <p>. With my mobile it's hard to use jsfiddle. I'll code it later with my computer if you can't.

Comment: You don't need jQuery for this, check my answer below. The code has comments and imo is very easy to understand with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a quick and easy shot at it, using simple vanilla Javascript:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('p')] // get all <p> as an array using spread syntax
  .filter(p => // so we can use array filter function on the list 
    p.children.length === 1 // only those that have exactly one child element
    && // AND
    p.firstElementChild.tagName === 'IMG' // which must be an <img>
    && // AND
    p.firstElementChild.style.float // and needs to have an inline float
  )
  .forEach(p => p.replaceWith(p.firstElementChild)) // and replace each p with its only child
```

```css
p {
  border: 10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <img src="uploads/image.jpg" style="float: right; width: 235px; height: 225px; margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px;" alt="Description" width="235" height="225" class="d-none d-md-block">
</p>

<br />

<p>
  <img src="uploads/image.jpg" style="float: right; width: 235px; height: 225px; margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px;" alt="Description" width="235" height="225" class="d-none d-md-block">
  <span>More than only the img</span>
</p>

<br />

<p>
  <img src="uploads/image.jpg" style="width: 235px; height: 225px; margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px;" alt="image not floating" width="235" height="225" class="d-none d-md-block">
</p>

<br />

<p><b>No img inside p</b></p>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!